# Waydroid bluetooth passthrough workaround

Tags: android, emulators

I recently discovered [waydroid](https://github.com/waydroid) to easily integrate android apps into my linux laptop. However [it doesn't support bluetooth](https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/issues/155).

So is there any workaround such to make waydroid work with bluetooth. Or is there any alternative to waydroid which supports bluetooth?

By "supports bluetooth" I mean that I could connect to any bluetooth device as if android was running on a native smartphone (the actual sending and receiving is handled by the bluetooth device of the laptop by sure).

Comment: Waydroid is a container, i.e., it works more or less like a VM so it doesn't have *direct* access to Bluetooth but should work with its own "emulated" hardware from the host. In what context do you actually need the containerized Android apps to use the host's Bluetooh hardware directly?